# Jquery if output is over 60 output "you won!" else "too bad you lost"

Tags: jquery

So I've got this script that outputs a random number between 0 and 100 every time you click on the button

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  for ( i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
      $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        var randNum = 0;
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

        $(".result").html(" "+randNum);
      });
  }; 

});
```

Now do I want to have the outcome to have something like "you won" when a score of 60 or higher has been obtained otherwise "you lose". I appreciate any help!

Comment: irrelevant to your question but I don't see why you need a loop here. As for your question you want `if(randNum >= 60){ // do "you won logic" } else{// do "you lose logic" }`

Comment: _"Now do I want ..."_ I dunno, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        var randNum = 0;
        var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        var winlose = randNum >= 60?'You win':'You lose';

        $(".result").html(winlose + ' ' +randNum);
    });
});
```